# Combine a list of lists in R according to name of the lists

Tags: r

How can I merge a list of lists so that list-objects with the same name are merged in the outer layer.

```
# List object 1
list_1 <- list(
  L1 <- list(
    A1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
  ),
  L2 <- list(
    A1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
))

names(list_1) <- c("layer_1", "layer_2")
names(list_1$layer_1) <- c("A1")
names(list_1$layer_2) <- c("A1")


# List object 2
list_2 <- list(
  L1 <- list(
    B1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
  ),
  L2 <- list(
    B1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
  ))

names(list_2) <- c("layer_1", "layer_2")
names(list_2$layer_1) <- c("B1")
names(list_2$layer_2) <- c("B1")

list_1_2 <- list(list_1, list_2)
```

Now I want to turn `list_1_2` so that it gets this structure (with the possible to include multiple lists of lists (e.g., list_3, list_4 osv, although always with the outer layer being called layer_1, layer_2 and layer_3):

```
# End result
list_1_2 <- list(
  L1 <- list(
    A1 <- c(1, 2, 3),
    B1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
  ),
  L2 <- list(
    A1 <- c(1, 2, 3),
    B1 <- c(4, 5, 6)
  ))

names(list_1_2) <- c("layer_1", "layer_2")
names(list_1_2$layer_1) <- c("A1", "B1")
names(list_1_2$layer_2) <- c("A1", "B1")

list_1_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
do.call("modifyList", list_1_2)
```

to get the output you want. This is the same as calling `modifyList(list_1_2[[1]], list_1_2[[2]])` but will also work if you have more lists in the collection